# Is it possible to retain custom attributes in a class instance after deserialization?

Tags: attributes, serialization, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a custom HTML helper for MVC.NET that would allow me to render object entities (Model Objects) as HTML forms. So I decided to do it using custom attributes such as html input type, readonly flag, css classes, etc. Similar in a way to LINQ Mapping attributes that set database related bindings for Table and Column. So I did write a custom attribute class, applied it to the same entities that I store in the database, but when I retrieve an entity class from a database to display in a View, all of my custom attributes are gone. Is there a way to retain my custom attributes, AFTER they come back from a database?